# How do I remove a part of a string?

Tags: python

I have a list of cities in the United States (some elements: `'Midlothian, VA', 'Ridley Park, PA', 'Johannesberg, CA', 'Sylva, NC', 'Kewwannee, IL', 'Superior, WI', 'Brewster, OH', 'Stillwater, MN'`). I've been trying to remove anything after the comma (since I only want the name, not the state). I tried many things, but I can't get it to work.
For example:

```
for i in US_cities_list:
    i = i.split(",")
    if len(i) == 2:
        x = i.pop(1)
        i = x
```

This still gives me the same output (`'Midlothian, VA', 'Ridley Park, PA', 'Johannesberg, CA', 'Sylva, NC', 'Kewwannee, IL', 'Superior, WI', 'Brewster, OH', 'Stillwater, MN'`). Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You don't seem to be saving your results anywhere. BTW, there's a much easier way: `city, state = element.split(", ")` or if you *really* don't care about the state, `city, _ = element.split(", ")`

Comment: Assigning `i = x` doesn't modify the original list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that assigning `i = x` doesn't modify
the original list. You can see this by adding `print(US_citites_list)` inside your loop and observe that the list never changes.

One solution is to build a new list with the modified strings:

```
cities_only = [i.split(",")[0] for i in US_cities_list]
```

Note that I take advantage of the fact that `i.split()` will always return a list of at least one element. If there is no comma in the string, there will only be one element. If there is a comma, then there will be two elements. This means there is no need to check the length of `i`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. This seems to work, but I don't understand how you have a `for` loop inside the list.

Comment: @hurb Look up "list comprehension Python" ... it is a very common and also powerful syntax which can replace a formal loop over a list.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen gotcha, thanks

Answer (score 3):

A regex replacement works nicely here:

```py
inp = ['Midlothian, VA', 'Ridley Park, PA', 'Johannesberg, CA', 'Sylva, NC', 'Kewwannee, IL', 'Superior, WI', 'Brewster, OH', 'Stillwater, MN']
output = [re.sub(r',.*', '', x) for x in inp]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['Midlothian', 'Ridley Park', 'Johannesberg', 'Sylva', 'Kewwannee', 'Superior',
 'Brewster', 'Stillwater']
```

Answer (score 2):

As Code-Apprentice pointed out, assigning `i = x` doesn't modify the original list.

One method of actually modifying the original list while keeping as much of your original code as possible would be:

```
for i, item in enumerate(US_cities_list):
    item = item.split(",")
    US_cities_list[i] = item[0]
```

Comment: What does `enumerate` do in this case?

Comment: `enumerate` makes it so you're iterating tuples of `(index, value)` for each item in a list .

Comment: what's the difference between `enumerate` and `zip`?

Comment: `zip` combines two iterables, whereas `enumerate` 'numberifies' a list~

Comment: @hurb You can find the docs for these functions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-funcs)